# Right way to use lxml to generate xml in python

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I'm trying to create xml that corresponds to structure of directory (with subdirectories and files in that subdirs). When I try to use this example: [Best way to generate xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844360/best-way-to-generate-xml-in-python) instead of output from example, that is:

```
<root>
  <child/>
  <child>some text</child>
</root>
```

I've got:

```
b'<root>\n  <child/>\n  <child>some text</child>\n</root>\n'
```

Why is it so?
Uses PyCharm IDE if it matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a change in Python 3.  `etree.tostring()` is returning a bytes literal, which is denoted by `b'string value'`.  Note that whenever you see `\n` in the bytes literal it means the same as a new line if you print it out to a file.

You can turn this into a regular string using `s = s.decode('utf-8')`.

Answer (score 0):

'\n' is a Line feed char (LF).

When you, for instance, save your output to a file and open it in some editor, you'll get what you expect.

Your output is fine.