# How To remove an Subement in xml file using python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I want to remove a specific element with all sub element which belongs to him.
to find the element I want to remove I'm want to use the id of tag or the name of the tag.

For example, given this etree object

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<root>
  <tag_folders>
    <folder id="1">Stars</folder>
    <folder id="2">Planet</folder>
    <folder id="3">Satellite</folder>
  </tag_folders>
  <tags>
    <tag>
      <name>Earth</name>
    </tag>
    <tag id="2">
      <name>Sun</name>
    </tag>
    <tag id="29">
      <name>Moon</name>
    </tag>
</tags>
</root>
```

for example I want to remove Moon with the id "29"

the output I want :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<root>
  <tag_folders>
    <folder id="1">Stars</folder>
    <folder id="2">Planet</folder>
    <folder id="3">Satellite</folder>
  </tag_folders>
  <tags>
    <tag>
      <name>Earth</name>
    </tag>
    <tag id="2">
      <name>Sun</name>
    </tag>
 </tags>

</root>
```

Here is my code :

```py
def remove_tag(root, tag_id_r):
    i = 0
    for tag in root.iter('tag'):
        tag_id = tag.get('id')
        if (tag_id == tag_id_r):
            #root.clear(tag)
            #root.remove(tag)
            #root[1][i].remove(tag)
        # print(i, tag_id, tag_id_r, root[1][i])
        i += 1

def main():
    with open("lib.xml", 'a') as f:
        tree = etree.parse('lib.xml')
        root = tree.getroot()

        remove_tag(root, input("What is the id of the tag you want to remove?"))

        f.seek(0)
        f.truncate()

        dom = minidom.parseString(etree.tostring(tree, encoding="utf-8"))
        print('\n'.join([line for line in dom.toprettyxml(indent=' '*2).split('\n') if line.strip()]), file=f)
main()
```

I tried everything in the comments but it doesn't work

Comment: If you can use `lxml` package, XSLT would make this very simple without a single loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove an element in ElementTree (which is what the question is tagged with, but no import is shown) you must first get the parent element (in this case `tags`). (lxml has the `.getparent()` method shown in Jack Fleeting's answer.)

Also, you shouldn't have to open the file and truncate it if you really want to overwrite it; just use the .write() method of the ElementTree object.

Example...

**XML Input** (lib.xml; "`</tags>`" added to make it well-formed)

```xml
<root>
  <tag_folders>
    <folder id="1">Stars</folder>
    <folder id="2">Planet</folder>
    <folder id="3">Satellite</folder>
  </tag_folders>
  <tags>
    <tag>
      <name>Earth</name>
    </tag>
    <tag id="2">
      <name>Sun</name>
    </tag>
    <tag id="29">
      <name>Moon</name>
    </tag>
  </tags>
</root>
```

**Python**

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree


def remove_tag(root, tag_id_r):
    tags_elem = root.find("tags")
    target_tag = tags_elem.find(f"tag[@id='{tag_id_r}']")
    if target_tag:
        tags_elem.remove(target_tag)
    else:
        print(f"A tag with the id \"{tag_id_r}\" cannot be found.")


def main():
    tree = etree.parse("lib.xml")
    root = tree.getroot()

    remove_tag(root, input("What is the id of the tag you want to remove? "))

    # Overwriting the input file. Are you sure that's a good idea?
    tree.write("lib.xml", encoding="utf-8")


main()
```

**XML Output** (updated lib.xml)

```xml
<root>
  <tag_folders>
    <folder id="1">Stars</folder>
    <folder id="2">Planet</folder>
    <folder id="3">Satellite</folder>
  </tag_folders>
  <tags>
    <tag>
      <name>Earth</name>
    </tag>
    <tag id="2">
      <name>Sun</name>
    </tag>
    </tags>
</root>
```

Comment: I have several functions, one to add tags, one to add folders... and sometimes the xml file doesn't exist so I have to create it and try it:
```python
with open("lib.xml", 'w') as f:
```
but it doesn't work for me and I don't know why.

Comment: @Souheil - Even if the xml file doesn't exist, you shouldn't have to create it like that. If it doesn't exist, create a new tree instead of parsing the existing file. The serialization of the tree (writing to a file) doesn't change.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
elems = """<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<root>
  <tag_folders>
    <folder id="1">Stars</folder>
    <folder id="2">Planet</folder>
    <folder id="3">Satellite</folder>
  </tag_folders>
  <tags>
    <tag>
      <name>Earth</name>
    </tag>
    <tag id="2">
      <name>Sun</name>
    </tag>
    <tag id="29">
      <name>Moon</name>
    </tag>
   </tags>
</root>
""" #note that the xml has been fixed

from lxml import etree
doc = etree.XML(elems)
to_del = doc.xpath('//name["Moon"]/parent::tag[@id="29"]')
for td in to_del:
    td.getparent().remove(td)    
print(etree.tostring(doc, pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True).decode())
```

Output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ASCII'?>
<root>
  <tag_folders>
    <folder id="1">Stars</folder>
    <folder id="2">Planet</folder>
    <folder id="3">Satellite</folder>
  </tag_folders>
  <tags>
    <tag>
      <name>Earth</name>
    </tag>
    <tag id="2">
      <name>Sun</name>
    </tag>
    </tags>
</root>
```

Comment: is there another way to replace "elem" because the content of the folder is not always the same. (sorry if my question is stupid but this is a new project and I didn't know before ElementTree).

Comment: @Souheil, but your example uses `ElementTree` (i.e., `xml.etree.ElementTree`). Maybe you meant `lxml`? *See* [What are the differences between lxml and ElementTree?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47229309/1422451)

Answer (score 0):

Another method.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc
html = """
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<root>
  <tag_folders>
    <folder id="1">Stars</folder>
    <folder id="2">Planet</folder>
    <folder id="3">Satellite</folder>
  </tag_folders>
  <tags>
    <tag>
      <name>Earth</name>
    </tag>
    <tag id="2">
      <name>Sun</name>
    </tag>
    <tag id="29">
      <name>Moon</name>
    </tag>
</root>
"""
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
tag29 = doc.select('tag#29')
# Or
# tag29 = doc.getElementByText('Moon',tag='tag')
tag29.remove()
print (doc.html)
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<root>
  <tag_folders>
    <folder id="1">Stars</folder>
    <folder id="2">Planet</folder>
    <folder id="3">Satellite</folder>
  </tag_folders>
  <tags>
    <tag>
      <name>Earth</name>
    </tag>
    <tag id="2">
      <name>Sun</name>
    </tag>
</root>
```